# Why am I getting a "401 Unauthorized" error in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Why am I getting a "401 Unauthorized" error in Maven?

Here's the error I'm getting when calling `mvn deploy` (full logs at the bottom):

`[INFO] BUILD FAILURE`
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]`

According to this [sonatype support page](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5073):

> "If you are receiving a 401 it is because maven is sending the wrong login credentials, or no credentials at all."

Below are the steps I've taken, below that are my full `settings.xml` and `pom.xml` files, and below that are the full logs from `mvn deploy` and `mvn deploy -e`.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I am just hitting wall after wall with Maven.

---

I followed [sonatype's checklist](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/11/what-to-do-when-nexus-returns-401/) when receiving a 401 error:

> **Checklist item 1**. *Make sure your username/password is correct by logging into the Nexus UI. If curl is installed on your machine, you can try deploying an artifact with...*

- I successfully logged in and out of the sonatype.org website, using the user/pass in `settings.xml`.
- I *attempted* to use `curl` to manually deploy an artifact, with the command

`[C:\]curl -u MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_USERNAME:MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/xbnjava-0.1.2-20140716.224928-1.pom --request PUT --data @pom.xml`

but got this error:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "pom.xml", this makes an empty POST.
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I ran it again with the `-k` option, and this time got only this:

```
Couldn't read data from file "pom.xml", this makes an empty POST.
```

I've never used curl before, so I'm at a loss on what to do with this information.

> **Checklist item 2**. *If there is no error output, ensure your user privileges are correctly configured on the server.  Make sure to drop the repo you just created.*

I don't know what "drop" means. I believe my privileges are properly installed, as I received this message from sonatype:

- Configuration has been prepared, now you can:
- Deploy snapshot artifacts into repository https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
- Deploy release artifacts into the staging repository https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2
- Promote staged artifacts into repository 'Releases'
- Download snapshot and release artifacts from group https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public
- Download snapshot, release and staged artifacts from staging group https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging

and I *have* successfully put [these items](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2-SNAPSHOT/) onto the server via `mvn deploy` in the past couple days.

The project's settings:

[image: project settings]

> **Checklist item 3**. *Make sure you have configured a server in `settings.xml` and that the server id is identical to the distribution repository id in pom.xml.*

- In `settings.xml`, settings/servers/server/id equals `ossrh`
- In `pom.xml`, distributionManagement/snapshotRepository/id equals `ossrh`

(full files are at the bottom)

> **Checklist item 4**. *Make sure your settings.xml is in the correct place (normally it’s _~/.m2/settings.xml).  You can check this by running mvn help:effective-settings.*

According to Maven's [settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Quick_Overview), settings.xml must be in one of two locations:

- The Maven install: `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`
- A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

Here's my setup:

- `settings.xml`: `C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.2.2\conf\settings.xml`
- `M2_HOME` is `C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.2.2`

Output for `mvn help:effective-settings`:

```
[C:\applications\utilities\curl]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-settings (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO]
Effective user-specific configuration settings:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2014-07-18T12:48:19                  -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective Settings for 'jeffy' on 'kermit-the-frog'                    -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:sc
hemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository</localRepository
>
  <servers xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <server>
      <username>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_USERNAME</username>
      <password>***</password>
      <id>ossrh</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <pluginGroups xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0">
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.310 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T12:48:19-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> **Checklist item 5**. *If the server is using https but the URL in your POM is http, you might get 401 as well.*

I don't understand which url it's referring to.

> **Checklist item 6**. *Use the latest version of Maven, as there is a known issue regarding 401: MNG-4469*

I am using the latest version:

```
[C:\]mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T09:51:42-04:00)
Maven home: C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\applications\programming\jdk_7_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

### ------------------

### Full `settings.xml` and `pom.xml` files

(Full logs for `mvn deploy` and `mvn deploy -e` below)

`settings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
     <server>
       <id>ossrh</id>
       <username>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_USERNAME</username>
       <password>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD</password>
     </server>
   </servers>

   <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
   <proxies></proxies>
   <mirrors></mirrors>
   <profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.github.aliteralmind</groupId>
   <artifactId>xbnjava</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>0.1.2</version>
   <name>XBN-Java</name>
   <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava</url>
   <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
   <organization>
      <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
   </organization>
   <description>XBN-Java is a collection of generically-useful backend (server side, non-GUI) programming utilities, featuring RegexReplacer and FilteredLineIterator. XBN-Java is the foundation of Codelet (http://codelet.aliteralmind.com).</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
      <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
      <version>7</version>
   </parent>

   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0</name>
         <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt</url>
      </license>
      <license>
         <name>Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0</name>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      </license>
   </licenses>

   <developers>
      <developer>
         <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
         <email>aliteralmind-github@yahoo.com</email>
         <roles>
            <role>Lead Developer</role>
         </roles>
      </developer>
   </developers>

   <issueManagement>
      <system>GitHub Issue Tracker</system>
      <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava/issues</url>
   </issueManagement>

   <distributionManagement>
      <snapshotRepository>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
   </distributionManagement>

   <scm>
      <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</connection>
      <url>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</url>
      <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</developerConnection>
   </scm>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.7</java.version>
      <jarprefix>R:\jeffy\programming\build\/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/download/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jarprefix>
   </properties>
<!--
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
 -->
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <artifacts>
                        <artifact>
                           <file>${jarprefix}-all.jar</file>
                           <type>jar</type>
                        </artifact>
                     </artifacts>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <profiles>
      <!--
      This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
      See: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven
      -->
      <profile>
         <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>release</name>
               <value>true</value>
            </property>
         </activation>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

### ------------------

### Full logs for `mvn deploy` and `mvn deploy -e`

`mvn deploy` output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.2\xbnjava-0.1.2.pom
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.2\download\xbnjava-0.1.2-all.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.2\xbnjava-0.1.2.jar
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom
2/6 KB
4/6 KB
6/6 KB
```

(Failure section:)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.204 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T11:25:17-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

`mvn deploy -e` output:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.2\xbnjava-0.1.2.pom
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.2\download\xbnjava-0.1.2-all.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.2\xbnjava-0.1.2.jar
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom
2/6 KB
4/6 KB
6/6 KB
```

(Failure section:)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.492 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T11:25:37-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xbnjava: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
   ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
   at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
   at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:149)
   ... 21 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
   at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:337)
   at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:268)
   at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
   at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
   ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:pom:0.1.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-staging (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
   at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
   at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
   at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:895)
   at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:522)
   at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:331)
   ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.2/xbnjava-0.1.2.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
   at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:573)
   at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:493)
   at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:474)
   at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:454)
   at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:871)
   ... 28 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: FYI: The "MY_USERNAME"/"PASSWORD" placeholders are only in this question. I use my real user/pass when logging in, and in the real settings file.

Comment: item 3: necessity for server id to match repository id is nuts, but unfortunately this is how it works, your answer helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I've had similar errors when trying to deploy a Gradle artefact to a Nexus Sonatype repository.  You will get a 401 Unauthorized error if you supply the wrong credentials (password etc).  You also get an error (and off the top of my head is also a 401) if you try to publish something to a releases repository **and that version already exists in the repository.**  So you might find that by publishing from the command line it works, but then when you do it from a script it fails (because it didn't exist in the repository the first time around).  Either publish using a different version number, or delete the old artefact on the server and republish.

The SNAPSHOTS repository (as opposed to the releases repository) allows you to overwrite a similarly numbered version, but your version number should have "-SNAPSHOT" at the end of it.

Comment: Unbelievable. It seems that `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT`, which is already created, interferes with my new `0.1.2` version, as you suggest. Changing it to `0.1.0` ("earlier"), or `0.1.2a`, or `0.1.3` ("later") results in the error I *was* dealing with before this one:

Comment: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project xbnjava: Failed to install artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:jar:0.1.3: R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.3\download\xbnjava-0.1.3-all.jar (The system cannot find the path specified) -> [Help 1]`. I didn't think I made any changes, but obviously eliminating that `-SNAPSHOT` from the version was a bad thing.

Comment: Why in the WORLD the error message would say something as nebulous and unhelpful as "401 Unauthorized"...

Comment: double check that the id for the repository you configured your credentials for (in your settings.xml or POM) matches the repository you want to deploy to. Just stumbled over this.

Comment: I also had the problem that there was already a release version 1.3.0 when I was trying to publish the 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT...

Comment: What if I get 401 but the artifacts are still being uploaded?

Comment: The error message you get when you deploy a release version that already exists is HTTP "400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request". I've worked as devops admin for some time and people were running constantly into this issue.

Comment: @aliteralmind Because when it comes to security, better error messages will also help attackers, not just users.

Comment: If it's none of the above, check if maybe the Nexus url has changed. In my case, it had, and although it was redirecting to the new url which worked fine when downloading, this failed miserably when attempting to upload the resulting artifact. I assume it's because the credentials are not resent to the redirected url.

Comment: I got Unauthorized also because of a permission issue. For some reason when mvn is being executed in a Docker container, not under 'root' user, (how the project was build there), it returns 401.

Answer (score 23):

One of the reasons for this error is when repositoryId is not specified or specified incorrectly. As mentioned already it should be the same as  in  section in settings.xml.
Couple of hints... Run mvn with -e -X options and check the debug output. It will tell you which repositoryId it is using:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = exe
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = c:\temp\build-test\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1 @ 
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryId = remote-repository
[DEBUG]   (f) repositoryLayout = default
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) uniqueVersion = true
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = https://nexus.url.blah.com/...
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 13.1
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

In this case it uses the default value "remote-repository", which means that something went wrong.

Apparently I have specified -DrepositoryID (note ID in capital) instead of -DrepositoryId.

Comment: This solved it for me, but I also found other projects in my workspace couldn't find our releases repo with the names being unique (they would look for artifacts in our Central proxy).  We're using 2.5.3 of the release plugin.  So in my `settings.xml`, I made both repo IDs identical again (snapshot and release) but then I added another declaration with a unique ID for our same release repo (basically an alias).  This allowed projects that required the unique name to refer to that, and the older projects that used the identical names to refer to them.  Our master-pom refers to the identical.

Answer (score 20):

just change in settings.xml these as aliteralmind says:

```
  <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_USERNAME</username>
      <password>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD</password>    
 </server>
```

you probably need to get the username / password from sonatype dot com.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Me too! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 10):

I had put a not encrypted password in the settings.xml .

I tested the call with curl

```
curl -u username:password http://url/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/myproject/api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/api-1.0-20160128.114425-1.jar --request PUT --data target/api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and I got the error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Artifactory configured to accept only encrypted passwords but received a clear text password."
  } ]
}
```

I retrieved my encrypted password clicking on my artifactory profile and unlocking it.

Comment: Hint: many curl implementations require options to come before the URL. In this case use `code curl -u username:password  --request PUT --data target/api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar http://url/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/myproject/api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/api-1.0-20160128.114425-1.jar` instead

Answer (score 7):

Also had 401's from Nexus. Having tried all the suggestions above and more without success I eventually found that it was a Jenkins setting that was in error.

In the Jenkins configuration for the failing project, we have a section in the 'Post Build' actions entitled 'Deploy Artifacts To Maven Repository'. This has a 'Repository ID' field which was set to the wrong value. It has to be the same as the repository ID in settings.xml for Jenkins to read the user and password fields:

[image: Jenkins Project Configuration]

```
 <servers>
    <server>
      <id>snapshot-repository</id>  <!-- must match this -->
      <username>deployment</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in @John's answer, the fact that there is already a `0.1.2-SNAPSHOT`, interfered with my new non-SNAPSHOT version `0.1.2`. Since the `401 Unauthorized` error is nebulous and unhelpful--and is normally associated to user/pass problems--it's no surprise that I was unable to figure this out on my own.

Changing the version to `0.1.3` brings me back to my original error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project xbnjava: Failed to install artifact com.github.aliteralmind:xbnjava:jar:0.1.3: R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.3\download\xbnjava-0.1.3-all.jar (The system cannot find the path specified) -> [Help 1].`

A sonatype support person also recommended that I remove the `<parent>` block from my POM (it's only there because it's in [the one from ez-vcard](https://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml), which is what I started with) and replace my `<distributionManagement>` block with

```
<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
  <repository>
    <id>ossrh</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
and then make sure that lines up with what's in your settings.xml:
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <username>your-jira-id</username>
      <password>your-jira-pwd</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

After doing this, running `mvn deploy` actually uploaded one of my jars for the very first time!!!

Output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.3\xbnjava-0.1.3.pom
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.3\download\xbnjava-0.1.3.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.3\xbnjava-0.1.3.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.3/xbnjava-0.1.3.pom
2/6 KB
4/6 KB
6/6 KB

Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.3/xbnjava-0.1.3.pom (6 KB at 4.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
310/310 B

Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (310 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
310/310 B

Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (310 B at 1.4 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.3/xbnjava-0.1.3.jar
2/630 KB
4/630 KB
6/630 KB
8/630 KB
10/630 KB
12/630 KB
14/630 KB
...
618/630 KB
620/630 KB
622/630 KB
624/630 KB
626/630 KB
628/630 KB
630/630 KB
```

*(Success portion:)*

```
Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.3/xbnjava-0.1.3.jar (630 KB at 474.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.632 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T15:09:25-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the full updated POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.aliteralmind</groupId>
  <artifactId>xbnjava</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.1.3</version>
  <name>XBN-Java</name>
  <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava</url>
  <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
  <organization>
     <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
  </organization>
  <description>XBN-Java is a collection of generically-useful backend (server side, non-GUI) programming utilities, featuring RegexReplacer and FilteredLineIterator. XBN-Java is the foundation of Codelet (http://codelet.aliteralmind.com).</description>

  <licenses>
     <license>
        <name>Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0</name>
        <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt</url>
     </license>
     <license>
        <name>Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
     </license>
  </licenses>

  <developers>
     <developer>
        <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
        <email>aliteralmind-github@yahoo.com</email>
        <roles>
           <role>Lead Developer</role>
        </roles>
     </developer>
  </developers>

  <issueManagement>
     <system>GitHub Issue Tracker</system>
     <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <scm>
     <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</connection>
     <url>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</url>
     <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</developerConnection>
  </scm>

  <properties>
     <java.version>1.7</java.version>
     <jarprefix>R:\jeffy\programming\build\/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/download/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jarprefix>
  </properties>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.8</version>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                 <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                    <artifacts>
                       <artifact>
                          <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                          <type>jar</type>
                       </artifact>
                    </artifacts>
                 </configuration>
              </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
     <!--
     This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
     See: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven
     -->
     <profile>
        <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
        <activation>
           <property>
              <name>release</name>
              <value>true</value>
           </property>
        </activation>
     </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

That's one big Maven problem out of the way. Only 627 more to go.

Answer (score 3):

We have had this issue quite recently and found out it was to do with the version of Maven we were using.  We were using 3.1.0 and could not upload to nexus, we kept getting 401's, we reverted back to 3.0.3 and the issue went away.

Easiest way to confirm is to work through the maven versions and run "mvn deploy" on your project.

Further details can be found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-421

Comment: Thanks.  Turned out to be my problem as well.  Eclipse was using the embedded version 3.6.3.  Switched it to 3.0.5 and it worked.  Terrible error message.  Wasted hours digging through authorization issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is the official explanation from sonatype nexus team about **401 - Unauthorized**

I recommend you to read [Troubleshooting Artifact Deployment Failures](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464668-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Deployment-Failures) for more information.

> Code 401 - Unauthorized
>
> Either no login credentials were sent with the request, or login
>   credentials which are invalid were sent.   Checking the "authorization
>   and authentication" system feed in the Nexus UI can help narrow this
>   down. If credentials were sent there will be an entry in the feed.
>
> If no credentials were sent this is likely due to a mis-match between
>   the id in your pom's distributionManagement section and your
>   settings.xml's server section that holds the login credentials.

Answer (score 3):

In Nexus version 3.13.0-01, the `id` in the POM's `distributionManagement/repository` section MUST match the `servers/server/id` and  `mirrors/mirror/id` in your maven settings.xml. I just replaced nexus v3.10.4 (with 3.13.0-01) and it wasn't needed to match for 3.10.4.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue. Had to pin the maven deploy plugin to specific version in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.2</version>
</plugin>
```

This version is what broke my builds:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-cli) @ dbl ---
```

Comment: It did help, Struggled for few days exploring artifactory if permission was revoked, then found out this.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by trying by typing `mvn clean install` in the command line. If you see that you are unable to transfer the artifacts to your local machine due to an authentication error 401, then you might not be using the correct settings.xml for authentication.

You can try `mvn clean install -s <path to you settings.xml>`.

In my case, I had the settings.xml on the root folder of my project, so I ran `mvn clean install -s ./settings.xml`, and it started successfully downloading the artifacts my projects depend on.

Answer (score 2):

Some users may have entered the email address instead of the user name by mistake. This may happen unconsciously when the name in the email address is the same as the user name.

Comment: This solved the problem for me using sonatype nexus 2.12. I had to change the email address to just a username in my settings.xml

Answer (score 2):

in my case, after encrypting password，I forgot to put `settings-security.xml` into ~/.m2。

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I need install Meven in Eclipse, because by default use the latest version.

Go to **Windows -> Preferences -> Maven ->  Installations -> add -> Directory**

Add my Maven version: C:\apache-maven-3.6.2

Then in **Run Configurations -> Maven build**

Goals: deploy

User Settings: C:\apache-maven-3.6.2\conf\settings.xml

In Windows, in C:\apache-maven-3.6.2\conf\settings.xml, I set the access to Nexus server:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>aaaaaa</username>
      <password>bbbbbbb</password>
    </server>    
  </servers>
```

Finally press **Run**

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was an incorrect id in the pom in the `distributionManagement` tag. Make sure those match.

```
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>correctId</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/user/_packaging/user/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>correctId</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/user/_packaging/user/maven/v1</url>
        <name>correctId</name>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And ofc. make sure you have and then you have the correct token in your setting.xml in .m2 folder in the server's tag. An IDE's maven in configured correctly (to pick up this config)

```
<server> 
    <id>correctId</id>
    <username>correctId</username> 
    <password>secretToken</password> 
</server>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I tried and rechecked everything. I was so focused in the Stack trace that I didn't read the last lines of the build before the Reactor summary and the stack trace:

```
[DEBUG] Using connector AetherRepositoryConnector with priority 3.4028235E38 for http://www:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
[INFO] Downloading: http://www:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/wdsuite/com.wdsuite.server.product/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.group:artifact.product:version-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in nexus (http://www:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/me/.m2/repository/com/group/project/version-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties
[INFO] Uploading: http://www:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/...-1.0.0-20141118.124526-1.zip
[INFO] Uploading: http://www:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/...-1.0.0-20141118.124526-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
```

This was the key : **"Could not find metadata"**. Although it said that it was an authentication error actually it got fixed doing a "rebuild metadata" in the nexus repository.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got the same "Could not find metadata" debug message but the actual error was another one: I used a wrong user name.

Answer (score 1):

There are two setting.xml in windows.

- `%MAVEN_HOME%\conf\`
- `%userprofile%\.m2\`

If `%userprofile%\.m2\setting.xml` takes effect, maven will not access `%MAVEN_HOME%\conf\setting.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this running Artifactory version 5.8.4. The "Set Me Up" function would generate settings.xml as follows:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP56eMPz8L12T5u4J6rWdqWqyhQ"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP56eMPz8L12T5u4J6rWdqWqyhQ"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
</servers>
```

After using the mvn deploy -e -X switch, I noticed the credentials were not accurate. I removed the *${security.getCurrentUsername()}* and replaced it with my username and removed *${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!""}* and just put my encrypted password which worked for me:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>AP56eMPz8L12T5u4J6rWdqWqyhQ</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>AP56eMPz8L12T5u4J6rWdqWqyhQ</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That sounds like you've got the values misconfigured elsewhere, since it's supposed to use values from the security object or fall back to those as defaults. But glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to transfer file:
>   http://mcpappxxxp.dev.chx.s.com:18080/artifactory/mcprepo-release-local/Shop/loyalty-telluride/01.16.03/loyalty-tell-01.16.03.jar.
>   Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

**Solution:**

In this case you need to change the version in the pom file, and try to use a new version.

Here 01.16.03 already exist so it was failing and when i have tried with the 01.16.04 version the job went successful.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error 401 deploying to Nexus 3 using M2Eclipse and I was able to figure out the root cause.

The problem is that M2Eclipse tries to deploy artifacts in parallel which is not permitted by Nexus. You can find more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74318208/4316647).

As a workaround you can deploy with a command line maven installation.

Answer (score 0):

Also, after you've updated your repository ids, make sure you run clean as `release:prepare` will pick up where it left off. So you can do:

`mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false` or

`mvn release:clean release:prepare`

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by wrong version, you can double check the **parent's version** and **lib's version**, to make sure they're correct and not duplicated, I've experienced same problem

Answer (score 0):

I got `401` error when used `mvn gpg:sign-and-deploy-file` command and the reason was that

```
//<maven_home>/conf/settings.xml
//To get `<maven_home>` run `mvn --version`
//for example

/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml
```

does not include `<server></server>` tag body that you can get via

```
LogIn to Sonatype -> Profile -> User Token -> Access User Token
//https://oss.sonatype.org/#profile;User%20Token

//it will generate something like
<server>
  <id>${server}</id>
  <username>{name}</username>
  <password>{pass}</password>
</server>

//where `${server}` is the same as `-DrepositoryId` parameter in `mvn gpg:sign-and-deploy-file` command
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I removed the server logon credentials for central from my setting.

```
    <server> 
        <id>central</id>
        <username>admin</username> 
        <password>******</password> 
    </server>

   <mirror>
        <id>central</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <name>maven-central</name>
        <url>http://www.localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/</url>
   </mirror>
```

I don't know why I did that, but its completely wrong since the central maven repo can be accessed anonymously. See my debug output that led to my error identification and resolution.

```
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://www.localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/ with username=admin, password=***
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue. In my case the reason was pretty stupid - github token I used for authorization was issued for the organization that doesn't own the repo I tried to publish into. So check repo title and ownership.

Answer (score 0):

If you were like me, running maven compile deploy from eclipse's maven run configuration, the issue could be related to eclipse's own embedded maven as described in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562847

The workaround is to run mvn compile deploy from CLI such as bash,
or to NOT use embedded maven in the eclipse's maven run configuration, and add an external maven (mine is in /usr/share/mvn), and voila, it'll say BUILD SUCCESS.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all items in .M2 folder. Then run **mvn clean package** to download all libs. Go to eclipse use maven update. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd had the same issue after trying all these solutions still I'd had the same issue until I checked the **settings.xml** file

Make sure that the **settings.xml** file Is **.xml** extension NOT **.xml.txt**
and that's because I created the file like I create any notepad file.

```
 C:\Users\muham> cd .m2
 C:\Users\muham\.m2> ls
```

I found this output

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/10/2022   1:27 PM                repository
-a----         5/10/2022   1:31 PM            177 settings.xml.txt
```

That means that my **settings.xml** file extension was **txt**

I changed its extension to .xml

```
C:\Users\muham\.m2> mv settings.xml.txt settings.xml
```

the output

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/10/2022   1:27 PM                repository
-a----         5/10/2022   1:31 PM            177 settings.xml
```

Now you can test and hopefully the error will vanish

Answer (score 0):

When running the staging process in an automated CI/CD pipeline (e.g. via GitLab), check that the variables for username and password in Settings -> CI/CD are set correctly.

If "Protect variable" is checked, check that the branch is also protected. Otherwise, the `401 Unauthorized` error will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Very old post, but in case someone crawls it and searches for an alternative answer after trying all of the great resources above, here is what worked for me:

In my case, mvn was being packaged from another directory than what was setup in the IDE (jetbrains-idea-ce).

[image: BuildTools Screenshot]

The `settings.xml` is being called from the `/.m2/settings.xml`, while the version that is triggering `mvn package` and `mvn deploy` is using another path dpkg-ed from apt, so `/usr/share/maven`.

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-56-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

What solved it for me is actually modifying  `/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml`

```
<settings>
      <server>
        <id></id>
<!-- <id> has to be the same as the <id> in pom.xml -->
        <username>USERNAME</username>
        <password>PASSWORD</password>
      </server>
 </settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because of the lack of JAVA_HOME and Path variables. I forgot to add these settings after downloading the Java SDK and it caused this cryptic error.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when trying to deploy to a Artifactory repository, the following solved the issue for me:

Go to the repository setting in artifactory and enable the point "**Force Maven Authentication**" and the 401 "Unauthorized" error should be gone.
(Of course you need to supply your credentials in the settings.xml file *at best in plain text to prevent issues*)

I guess by default, even through you supply the right credentials in the settings.xml file, they don't get used and you get the Unauthorized exception.