# Maven not properly passing encrypted passwords to nexus

Tags: java, maven

What I want to do:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.REDACTED_DOMAIN/content/repositories/REDACTED_ID/archetype-catalog.xml
```

but I get this error:

```
org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

Our internal nexus is protected with LDAP, as is typical. I've got the following setup:

```
~/.m2/
    settings.xml
    settings-security.xml
```

The contents of my `settings-security.xml` look like this:

```
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>{hashed characters here}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

The contents of my `settings.xml` file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>REDACTED_ID</id>
      <username>REDACTED_USER</username>
      <password>{hashed-characters}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

From what I can tell, I have set everything correctly. I thought that maybe my password itself was the cause of the issue (I use a special character that sometimes causes issues with bash if not properly escaped). To see if this was the issue, I downloaded the [maven settings decoder](https://github.com/jelmerk/maven-settings-decoder). The decoder, shows that my password is correct when brought back to clear text.

I tried restarting in case my settings were cached /tmp or memory, but this was not the case either.

I thought that maybe I needed to reinstall maven, so with homebrew (I'm on osx) I uninstalled and reinstalled maven to no effect.

I ran mvn with `-X` and it shows that my settings are being loaded:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/redacted/.m2/settings.xml
```

and nothing seems out of the ordinary from the global settings. What else is left? What should I do? The next step does not seem obvious to me and I'm somewhat at my wits end.

EDIT: Full debug output, as requested.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T09:41:47-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix archetype from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix archetype to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin from repository central
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin to 2.4 from repository central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [archetype:generate]
[DEBUG] Style:   Aggregating
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix archetype from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix archetype to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin from repository central
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin to 2.4 from repository central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] --- init fork of org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1 for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) ---
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] --- exit fork of org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:1 for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) ---
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <archetypeArtifactId>${archetypeArtifactId}</archetypeArtifactId>
  <archetypeCatalog default-value="remote,local">${archetypeCatalog}</archetypeCatalog>
  <archetypeGroupId>${archetypeGroupId}</archetypeGroupId>
  <archetypeRepository>${archetypeRepository}</archetypeRepository>
  <archetypeVersion>${archetypeVersion}</archetypeVersion>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <filter>${filter}</filter>
  <goals>${goals}</goals>
  <interactiveMode default-value="${settings.interactiveMode}">${interactiveMode}</interactiveMode>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <remoteArtifactRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=134, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=60, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=6, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=125, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=149, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.4:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-catalog:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-descriptor:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-registry:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-common:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]       net.sourceforge.jchardet:jchardet:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[DEBUG]          xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[DEBUG]       jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[DEBUG]             org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.8:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.21:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api:jar:1.0-alpha-16:compile
[DEBUG]             org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3:compile
[DEBUG]       antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[DEBUG]       asm:asm:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       asm:asm-commons:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       asm:asm-util:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       asm:asm-analysis:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       asm:asm-tree:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-script-interpreter:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-catalog:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-descriptor:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-registry:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-common:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: net.sourceforge.jchardet:jchardet:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   Included: xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
[DEBUG]   Included: jdom:jdom:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: oro:oro:jar:2.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.21
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-6
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3
[DEBUG]   Included: antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7
[DEBUG]   Included: asm:asm:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: asm:asm-commons:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: asm:asm-util:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: asm:asm-analysis:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: asm:asm-tree:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-script-interpreter:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993]
[DEBUG] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: site.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.SiteResourceLoader'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath,site'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: runtime.log.invalid.references => 'false'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[DEBUG] *******************************************************************
[DEBUG] Starting Apache Velocity v1.5 (compiled: 2007-02-22 08:52:29)
[DEBUG] RuntimeInstance initializing.
[DEBUG] Default Properties File: org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/velocity.properties
[DEBUG] LogSystem has been deprecated. Please use a LogChute implementation.
[DEBUG] Default ResourceManager initializing. (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl)
[DEBUG] ResourceLoader instantiated: org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader
[DEBUG] ResourceLoader instantiated: org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.SiteResourceLoader
[DEBUG] ResourceCache: initialized (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl)
[DEBUG] Default ResourceManager initialization complete.
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Literal
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Macro
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Include
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach
[DEBUG] Created '20' parsers.
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : initialization starting.
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : allowInline = true : VMs can be defined inline in templates
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : allowInlineToOverride = false : VMs defined inline may NOT replace previous VM definitions
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : allowInlineLocal = false : VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : autoload off : VM system will not automatically reload global library macros
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : Velocimacro : initialization complete.
[DEBUG] RuntimeInstance successfully initialized.
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) archetypeCatalog = https://nexus.REDACTED_DOMAIN/content/repositories/REDACTED_ID/archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /Users/REDACTED_USER/git
[DEBUG]   (f) interactiveMode = true
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///Users/REDACTED_USER/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) remoteArtifactRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@5173200b
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: https://nexus.REDACTED_DOMAIN/content/repositories/REDACTED_ID/archetype-catalog.xml/archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: https://nexus.REDACTED_DOMAIN/content/repositories/REDACTED_ID/archetype-catalog.xml
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog https://nexus.REDACTED_DOMAIN/content/repositories/REDACTED_ID/archetype-catalog.xml
org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1005)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.downloadCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.source.RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.getArchetypeCatalog(RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetypeManager.getRemoteCatalog(DefaultArchetypeManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeSelector.getArchetypesByCatalog(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeSelector.selectArchetype(DefaultArchetypeSelector.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
   Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to initial list)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :
```

Comment: share more of those error logs  with debug true and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830610/why-am-i-getting-a-401-unauthorized-error-in-maven

Comment: @nullpointer I've attached the logs. I took a look at the link you shared. It has some useful information in it, but I don't think it's what is affecting me. I can curl the `archetype.xml` file using the `-u` basic auth flag without issue, so I don't think this is a server side issue (especially because I'm just asking maven to perform a GET and I'm not relying on a particular state, like you would if you were trying to release an artifact like he was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good and bad news for you: just check the source and traced the issue down to `RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource`. Have a look at your request. How is Maven supposed to associate your `-DarchetypeCatalog` value with a valid server id? It can't, you have to tell! Here is the bad news, you can't tell because the repository id is hardcoded in the aformentioned class. Create a new server element in your `settings.xml` with the id `archetype` and it should work. If you are in question, you can debug down to [`RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/xref/org/apache/maven/archetype/source/RemoteCatalogArchetypeDataSource.html) and you'll see how a Wagon instance in populated with those type of information, along with your credentials.

Comment: Adding a new server section id'd `archetype` seems to work fine, but by your description this should be performing some pattern matching? I've updated the question to better show that the `REDACTED_ID` is actually in the URL of the archetype. This solves the immediate problem of generating a project from an archetype, but I can see a future where I have to try and add new `<server>` elements for every blocked situation I run into, down the line. Is there a better ID scheme I should be using instead?

Comment: No, it should not. The approach with the `REDACTED_ID` in the URL is brittle, pattern matching is brittle because it would require us to impose a specific URL style which is likely to be impossible. The server id is not linked to a repo by design. You are better off to use the proposed solution so far. You can of course analyze the code and provide a PR to avoid this duplicate server id maintenance, I'd be happy to review it.

Comment: I don't have a better solution in mind, I was just trying to see if I was understanding the usage correctly (which I do, but only now). I'll be using your solution as-is. Thank you!

Comment: Please also try [this](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/faq.html#authentication) and tell me if it is working. We can at least improve the documentation on this and add an IT for it. Mind to create an issue for?

Comment: I just tried it. I removed the "archetype" server section and then used that -D option where I manually specify the ID, however it doesn't seem to work. (It's a new error, different from the original.) Where would you like me to create an issue? I'll attach my log output to it