# nexus-staging-maven-plugin returns 401 without information

Tags: maven, sonatype

I am working on getting [Anonimatron](https://github.com/realrolfje/anonimatron) available as libary in the central Maven Repository. In order to do that I followed the documentation in [the sonatype documentation](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#nexus-staging-maven-plugin-for-deployment-and-release). The nexus staging plugin gives me a 401 error when running `mvn deploy` and I can't figure out why because it does not tell me what is going on.

I have a working account at [oss.sonatype.org](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~anonimatron), and I have created a user access token there. The access token is stored in the servers section of my maven `~/.m2/settings.xml` like so (token removed for reasons):

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <username>USER_TOKEN</username>
        <password>USER_PASSPHRASE</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Then, in my maven https://github.com/realrolfje/anonimatron/blob/feature/anonimatron-as-library/pom.xml file I added the nexus staging plugin:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-release</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
[...]
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
        <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn deploy`, I get the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.7:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project anonimatron: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.rolfje.anonimatron:anonimatron:jar:javadoc:1.9.3-20180512.204932-1 from/to sonatype-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/rolfje/anonimatron/anonimatron/1.9.3-SNAPSHOT/anonimatron-1.9.3-20180512.204932-1-javadoc.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

To check wether my token is indeed valid, I tried uploading with curl:

```
curl -u USER_TOKEN:USER_PASSPHRASE \
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/rolfje/anonimatron/anonimatron/1.9.3-SNAPSHOT/anonimatron-1.9.3-20180512.093802-1-javadoc.jar \
--request PUT --data target/anonimatron-1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This succeeds and I can see the uploaded jar appear in the Nexus Repository Manager.

I have executed the same steps as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830610/why-am-i-getting-a-401-unauthorized-error-in-maven) but since I have not uploaded anything yet, version numbers can not collide, although I did do a manual javadoc upload at the end. Since that is a snapshot, and it worked, I think my problem is with the nexus-staging-maven-plugin.

What I am searching for is a way to debug the nexus-staging-maven-plugin so that I know why it is failing. It does not tell me which credentials it is using, wether it loaded those from the settings.xml file, and what exact steps it is taking, even if I run mvn with -e and -X flags.

Comment: You need to have two entries in `<server>`..one with the id `sonatype-snapshots` and one with the id `sonatype-release`...

Comment: No change in behaviour. That is not only incorrect according to the documentation, but it also doesn't work (I tried it just now). In the plugin configuration, there is a "serverId" which must match the server id in the settings.xml.

Comment: So first step is to remove the nexus staging plugin and just try to deploy a SNAPSHOT which should work if permissions etc. are correctly configured...

Comment: <correction>: I got that to work. So the problem seems to be in the nexus plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a deploy with the standard maven-deploy plugin, as @khmarbaise mentioned, did seem to work. I reported this problem to sonatype as part of issues 
[OSSRH-39766](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-39766) and [OSSRH-39777](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-39777).

Joel regenerated my permissions and now the nexus release plugin seems to be working. Note that this could also be caused by the maven-deploy which might have "primed" something.

All in all, the nexus release plugin could do with some improvements on the logging, particularly:

1. What profile is used to execute the steps
2. What step (exactly) is being executed
3. If there is a 401, tell which userid was used to execute that step and from which environment that was fetched (command line, settings.xml, etc).

I see some people struggling with the nexus plugin, while the plugin should actually make life easier.

Thanks to SonaType for the fast and helpful responses!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <username>{YOUR_JIRA_USERNAME}</username>
        <password>{YOUR_JIRA_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Also, update your pom.xml:

```
<distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

1. **Make sure repository id and server id matches.** 
   In this example, the id is "ossrh".
2. **Also, note that the username and password should be same as your jira login**.  That's it `mvn clean deploy` will now upload your jar to sonatype repoditory. Happy Deploying!!