# Authentication failes with 401 while intelij maven downloading specific pom from nexus but is opened from url

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, nexus

getting below error while running mvn install on intelij project:

"Could not transfer artifact ... from... public  < *nexus repository url which define in setting.xml correctly under mirror with correct id configuration and server etc* >
Authentication failed for <.pom inside previous url that mentioned > 401 Unauthorized"

I can login to mirror url that provide in settings.xml with the username/pass provided under server definition and access that .pom etc.

any idea what I am missing inside intelij to get it fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure - where and when do you get this error - when **Synchronizing** Maven project in Maven tool window? What result do you get for `mvn install` from the command line?

Comment: What is the authentication type of the repository? Double check your credentials are specified correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24831550/2000323